# ¿Cómo cancelar/abortar solicitud AJAX en Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Si ejecuto una función a una URL del servidor y luego por cualquier motivo quiero cancelarla.

como puedo hacer esto?

Escribí este código se ejecuta bien, pero no cancela la solicitud:

```
 var reportPlays = null;

   function exportReportPlays() {
        reportPlays = $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '@Url.Action("Report", "PurchaseReport", new {area="Admin"})',
                data: { filterModel: $('#filterincomesreportsform').serialize(), report: 2 },
                success: function (data) {
                    checkReport("Generando reporte de reproducciones");
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert('Error al programar el reporte');
                }
             });
        }
```

// AQUI TRATO DE ABORTAR / CANCELAR LA SOLICITUD

```
 function cancelReport(idReport) {
            console.log(reportPlays);
            if (idReport === 2) {
                reportPlays.abort();
                 console.log(reportPlays.readyState);
            }
                
         }
```

Comment: Tienes alguna salida del log al llamar a `cancelReport()`? Algun mensaje de error?

Comment: Gracias F Igor ... No tengo ninguna salida de error se ejecuta bien pero no cancela la solicitud

Comment: ¿Dónde y cómo ejecutas la función `cancelReport()`?

Comment: Triby alli mismo debajo de la funcion exportReportPlays()